# Calculated Total in Descending Order - view in Group By

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, list-view, calculated-column-formula, classic-experience

Is it possible to sort in descending order the calculated total based on group by?

See pic below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can achieve it through power apps, I found a link for you that is similar to your needs, I hope it will help you.https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/group-by-with-sum-and-count-in-sharepoint-list/td-p/760480

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to sort the list view based on **Totals** (Sum) of SharePoint list column.

You can sort the SharePoint list view by original column (Total Steps) value.

**Related documentations**:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)
2. [Use grouping to modify a list or library view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-grouping-to-modify-a-list-or-library-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I can sort the Total Steps by original column.                                             
Do you have any recommendation to do this? How about using SP Designer?

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using?